# i am facing issue "panic: runtime error: index out of range" when create 2D array with make method in golang

Tags: arrays, go

> I am new in golang and try to learn with small examples.

So I am trying to create a 2D array and assign a value but I am stuck here can anyone help me. here is my code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    letters := make([][]string,0,2)
    letters[0][0] = "a"
    letters[0][1] = "b"
    letters[1][0] = "c"
    letters[1][1] = "d"

    fmt.Println(letters)
}
```

I am getting error when I run this code

> panic: runtime error: index out of range

Answer (score 1):

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Array types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types)
>
> An array is a numbered sequence of elements of a single type, called
>   the element type. The number of elements is called the length and is
>   never negative.
>
> [Slice types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types)
>
> A slice is a descriptor for a contiguous segment of an underlying
>   array and provides access to a numbered sequence of elements from that
>   array. A slice type denotes the set of all slices of arrays of its
>   element type. The value of an uninitialized slice is nil.
>
> [Making slices, maps and channels](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels)
>
> The built-in function make takes a type T, which must be a slice, map
>   or channel type, optionally followed by a type-specific list of
>   expressions. It returns a value of type T (not *T). The memory is
>   initialized as described in the section on initial values.
>
> [Appending to and copying slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices)
>
> The built-in functions append and copy assist in common slice
>   operations. For both functions, the result is independent of whether
>   the memory referenced by the arguments overlaps.
>
> The variadic function append appends zero or more values x to s of
>   type S, which must be a slice type, and returns the resulting slice,
>   also of type S.

---

In Go, arrays and slices are not the same thing. Your `make([][]string,0,2)` statement creates a 2D slice. Here is your 2D slice with initial values,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    letters := make([][]string, 2)
    letters[0] = append(letters[0], "a", "b")
    letters[1] = append(letters[1], "c", "d")
    fmt.Println(letters)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/l40xv_7W5h

Output:

```
[[a b] [c d]]
```

Comment: Thank you @peterSO